# Is this a bug in dynamic?

Tags: c#, dynamic, compiler-bug

When implementing dynamic dispatch using `dynamic` on a generic class, and the generic type parameter is a private inner class on another class, the runtime binder throws an exception.

For example:

```
using System;

public abstract class Dispatcher<T> {
    public T Call(object foo) { return CallDispatch((dynamic)foo); }

    protected abstract T CallDispatch(int foo);
    protected abstract T CallDispatch(string foo);
}

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        TypeFinder d = new TypeFinder();

        Console.WriteLine(d.Call(0));
        Console.WriteLine(d.Call(""));
    }

    private class TypeFinder : Dispatcher<CallType> {
        protected override CallType CallDispatch(int foo) {
            return CallType.Int;
        }

        protected override CallType CallDispatch(string foo) {
            return CallType.String;
        }
    }

    private enum CallType { Int, String }
}
```

Here, a `RuntimeBinderException` will be thrown with the message

> 'Dispatcher.CallDispatch(int)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

The reason for the inaccessibility is that the type parameter `T` is the private `CallType` which `Dispatcher<T>` cannot access. Therefore, `CallDispatch` must be inaccessible - but it isn't, because it's accessible as `T`.

Is this a bug with `dynamic`, or is this not supposed to be supported?

Comment: Given that this is a partial class the problem might lie elsewhere (cause obviously this isn't the only file).

Comment: Alxandr: this is the only file. The partial was there because I had used it before as a partial class and forgot to remove that.

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. I'd surmise that things are made private for the exact reasons your code is exhibiting - to not be called where it oughtn't be.

Comment: I've opened a query on Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/672411/bug-in-dynamic-dispatch-when-using-generic-type-parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug.  If you can make the call statically (and you can), you should be able to make it dynamically.

Specifically, the following code works:

```
using System;

public abstract class Dispatcher<T> {
    public T Call(object foo)
    {
        return CallDispatch(((object)(dynamic)foo).ToString());
    }

    protected abstract T CallDispatch(int foo);
    protected abstract T CallDispatch(string foo);
}

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        TypeFinder d = new TypeFinder();

        Console.WriteLine(d.Call(0));
        Console.WriteLine(d.Call(""));
    }

    private class TypeFinder : Dispatcher<CallType> {
        protected override CallType CallDispatch(int foo) {
            return CallType.Int;
        }

        protected override CallType CallDispatch(string foo) {
            return CallType.String;
        }
    }

    private enum CallType { Int, String }
}
```

Note that I've used `ToString()` to make the static type known, the C# compiler and CLR allow this context to access the private type `CallType`, so the DLR should allow it as well.

Comment: I believe the question is "why can I return the private enum CallType as the generic return value from my Call method even though it's a private class member?" - nothing to do with whether you can/can't make the call, the OP freely states that he gets an error at runtime.  (I agree, it should cause an error at both runtime and  compile time or at neither, but that's not the question)

Comment: @Nathan: If `Dispatcher<CallType>` doesn't have sufficient access to make the call, my version would fail.  But my code compiles and runs without error.  Hence everything needed is accessible, and the DLR is wrong to raise an error stating otherwise.

Comment: Nathan: No, my question was: "Why can't I make this call dynamically when I can make it statically? Is it a bug, or am I missing something?"

Comment: configurator: fair enough, I suggest you make your question clearer - several people, myself included have come up with answers to what they thought was your question.  Apologies to Ben.

Comment: Not every statically valid call is valid dynamically. For example: `IList<int> x = new int[10]; Console.WriteLine(x.Count);` works fine - but if you use `dynamic x = new int[10]; Console.WriteLine(x.Count);` it won't, because `Count` is explicitly implemented.

Comment: @Jon: Perhaps the name cannot be found, but I claim if it is found, it should be equally accessible.

Comment: @Ben: My point is that there are subtleties at work beyond "if it works statically, it should work dynamically". Don't forget at this point it's not using it as a generic method (it's not thinking of it as T any more), so it's trying to call a method whose return type is inaccessible. I don't know whether I'd classify it as a bug or just another dynamic gotcha. The precise nature of what "should" work is pretty ill-defined.

Comment: @Jon: I think the return type still is `T`.  The lookup is still being done in `Dispatcher<T>`, since the dynamic variable is an argument, not the object of method invocation.

Comment: @Ben: Doh, you're right. That's not the first time I've been tripped up by that in this example...

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug because the following static typing change should be equivalent

```
using System;

public abstract class Dispatcher<T>
{
    public T Call(int foo) { return CallDispatch(foo); }
    public T Call(string foo) { return CallDispatch(foo); }

    protected abstract T CallDispatch(int foo);
    protected abstract T CallDispatch(string foo);
}
```

And it works.

This issue seems to be an issue with the compiler and the dlr calls it makes and the static information the compiler includes in the invocation. It can be worked around with the open source framework [ImpromptuInterface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) that manually setups the dlr calls. With Impromptu by setting the context to `this` it's getting access permissions from the runtime type which will be TypeFinder.

```
using System;
using ImpromptuInterface.Dynamic;
public abstract class Dispatcher<T>
{
    protected CacheableInvocation _cachedDynamicInvoke;

    protected Dispatcher()
    {
        _cachedDynamicInvoke= new CacheableInvocation(InvocationKind.InvokeMember, "CallDispatch", argCount: 1, context: this);
    }

    public T Call(object foo)
    {
        return (T) _cachedDynamicInvoke.Invoke(this, foo);
    }

    protected abstract T CallDispatch(int foo);
    protected abstract T CallDispatch(string foo);
}
```